# Magento 2 How to show column on the basis of admin config value in admin custom grid by using UiComponent?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, system-config, custom-admin-grid

I had created a Custom Admin Grid by using uiComponent in which I am showing Order Details, please check below Screenshot

[image]

I had created System Configuration to show IGST, CST, SGST field or not, if it enables from admin then I will show this in grid otherwise not.

**Code:**

```
         <column name="price_igst">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">IGST</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="price_cgst">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CGST</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="price_sgst">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SGST</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Please help me how to do it?

Comment: `<argument name="testHelperWithParams" xsi:type="helper" helper="Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Argument\Handler\TestHelper::testMethod">`

Have you tried this? I don't know how it works in `UI component` but it works in `layout` files.

Comment: @MohitRane I don't think it will work in UiComponent, I will do some RND and post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add to your UI component a new tag

```
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">you.provaider.name</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </container>
</container>
```

if you have container listing_top in your ui component file, just add the tag columns_control to it.

Comment: Current I am already managing it by column control but I need to remove the field from column control aswell if it is disabled from admin configuration